# Performance with pagination

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

## Question

Given the following query:

```
MATCH (t:Tenant)-[:lives_in]->(:Apartment)-[:is_in]->(:City {name: 'City1'})
RETURN t
ORDER BY t.id
LIMIT 10
```

So: "Give me the first 10 tenants that live in City1"

With the sample data below, the database will get hit for every single apartment in City1 and for every tenant that lives in each of these apartments.
If I remove the `ORDER BY` this doesn't happen.
I am trying to implement pagination so I need the `ORDER BY`. How to improve the performance on this?

## Sample data

```
UNWIND range(1, 5) as CityIndex
CREATE (c:City { id: CityIndex, name: 'City' + CityIndex})
WITH c, CityIndex
UNWIND range(1, 5000) as ApartmentIndex
CREATE (a:Apartment { id: CityIndex * 1000 + ApartmentIndex, name: 'Apartment'+CityIndex+'_'+ApartmentIndex})
CREATE (a)-[:is_in]->(c)
WITH c, a, CityIndex, ApartmentIndex
UNWIND range(1, 3) as TenantIndex
CREATE (t:Tenant { id: (CityIndex * 1000 + ApartmentIndex) * 10 + TenantIndex, name: 'Tenant'+CityIndex+'_'+ApartmentIndex+'_'+TenantIndex})
CREATE (t)-[:lives_in]->(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the ORDER BY, cypher can lazily evaluate the tenants and stop at 10 rather than matching every tenant in City1. However, because you need to order the tenants, the only way it can do that is to fetch them all and then sort.

If the only labels that can live in apartments is Tenants then you could possibly save a Filter step by removing the `Tenant` in your query like `MATCH (t)-[:lives_in]->(:Apartment)...`.

You might want to check the profile of your query as well and see if it uses the [index backed order by](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/query-tuning/advanced-example/#advanced-query-tuning-example-index-backed-order-by)

What sort of numbers are you expecting back from this query? What's the worst case number of tenants in a given city?

**EDIT**

I was hoping a USING JOIN on t would use the index to improve the plan but it does not.
The query performs slightly better if you add a redundant relation from the tenant to the city:

```
MATCH (t:Tenant)-[:CITY]->(:City {name: 'City1'})
RETURN t
ORDER BY t.id 
LIMIT 10
```

and similarly by embedding the city name onto the tenant- no major gains. I tested for 150,000 tenants in City1, perhaps the gains are more visible as you approach millions, but not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The worst case: Millions, so I can't just live with it.

Comment: Is the City always the main filter? Or do you want to sort millions of tenants based on other criteria as well?

Comment: Let's assume it's the only filter

Comment: And: It's not directly about the sort. The sort is only a means to an end, this end being a  stable pagination. So, if that stable pagination can be achieved differently, that's fine as well

Comment: Does this make a difference: MATCH (t:Tenant)-[:lives_in]->(:Apartment)-[:is_in]->(:City {name: 'City1'})
USING JOIN ON t
RETURN t
ORDER BY t.id
LIMIT 10

Assume you have an index on Tenant.id

Comment: Unfortunately not. The query plan is exactly the same

Comment: I tried some more options but sadly, without much luck. The query still returns in milliseconds though. Edited my answer.